# Regular expression search in Visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, search, pattern-matching

The code that I am working with has tons of style that I want to remove. Here is the code snippet

```
asp:Label ID="LabelMeterNo" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" 
Style="z-index: 126; left: 72px;  top: 203px" Text="MeterNo"
Width="136px"></asp:Label>
```

The previous programmer used the z-index and position for every single control on the page. There are too many to search and find them one by one. Is there a regular expression that will catch this

```
Style="z-index: 126; left: 72px;  top: 203px"
Style="z-index: 124; left: 216px;
             top: 261px"
Style="z-index: 124; left: 216px;
             top: 291px"
```

There are certainly more combination of this. Notice the new line character in 2 and 3 example above.

What I would want is search for

```
Style="Z-index:126; left:72px; right;200px; top:23px; position:relative"
```

That is start from **Style="Z-index** and end at the **quotation mark**. Is there a way to do it?

[Here is a page that can be used for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means a regex expert so this can probably be cleaned/fixed a bit but since I just found out today about Visual Studio's interesting regex syntax I thought I'd give this a shot. This works for me with your test data in Visual Studio:

`Style\=\"[Zz]-index\:[a-zA-Z0-9; \::Cc]+\"`

Note some characters are escaped like =, ", : and I also use :Cc to match the newline. You may want to do something to ignore the case for the word Style as well.